# How can i translate this code into java?

Tags: java, physics, vector

My only problem translating the code from this question/answer is the Vector2 method. In the web i could only find this replacement (Vector2f). But i can not import it : can't resolve reference. Also i do not understand the use of`Velocity` as is.  Can i just do it each for posx and posy?

```
ublic void update() {
    if (posy < 1920-radius) {
        Velocity += gravitation * TimeStep;
    }
    Velocity -= Vector(Math.pow(Luftwiderstandinnewton, remainingTime),
            (Math.pow(Luftwiderstandinnewton, remainingTime))
            * Velocity;
    //Position
            posy+= Velocity * TimeStep;

    if (posx < 0 +radius|| posx > 1080 -radius) {
        // We've hit a vertical (side) boundary
        if (posx < 0 +radius) {
            remainingTime = -posx / velocityy;
            posx = 0+radius;
        } else {
            remainingTime = (posx - 1080-radius) / velocityx;
            posx = 1080-radius;
        }

        // Apply friction
        Velocity -=((Math.pow(stein, remainingTime)+
                Math.pow(stein, remainingTime)))
                * Velocity;

        // Invert velocity
        velocityx = -velocityx;
        posx = posx + velocityx * remainingTime;
    }

    if (posy < 0 +radius || posy > 1920-radius) {
        // We've hit a horizontal boundary
        if (posy < 0 +radius) {
            remainingTime = -posy / velocityy;
            posy = 0 +radius;
        } else {
            remainingTime = (posy - 1920-radius) / velocityy;
            posy = 1920-radius;
        }

        // Remove excess gravity
        velocityy -= remainingTime * gravitation;

        // Apply friction
        Velocity -= ((Math.pow(gras, remainingTime) +
                Math.pow(gras, remainingTime)))
                * Velocity;

        // Invert velocity
        velocityy = -velocityy;

        // Re-add excess gravity
        float OldVelocityY = (float) velocityy;
        velocityy += remainingTime * gravitation;
        // If velocity changed sign again, clamp it to zero
        if (velocityy * OldVelocityY <= 0)
            velocityy = 0;

        posy = posy + velocityy * remainingTime;
    }
}
```

[Ball Physics : Smoothing the final bounces as the ball comes to rest](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28847/ball-physics-smoothing-the-final-bounces-as-the-ball-comes-to-rest)

```
org.newdawn.slick.geom.Vector2f
```

Any ideas?